# How to multiply every element in array in python

Tags: python

In array `[1,5,6]`, I have 3 elements and I want to multiply them like: `1 * 5 * 6`

I don't want did it like that:

```
array[0] * array[1] * array[2]
```

I want it automatically no matter how big the array is.

Comment: There's a function in `math` library. [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/math.html#math.prod)

Answer (score 2):

You can [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) your array by [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul)tiplication:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

array = [1, 5, 6]

reduce(mul, array)
# 30
```